# Converting an Array of primatives to and from a single string

Tags: c#

I'm writing a plug-in for a program where I can attribute objects in the program by appending "User Strings" to each object that have a key string and a value string. However, in some cases I need to store an array of a primitive type rather then just a single value. So what is the easiest way to convert an array of values into a string, and then later take that same string and convert it back into the original array of values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a couple of extension methods to convert your collections to/from delimited strings, passing in a custom delegate to perform the conversion of each item:

```
public static string ToDelimitedString<T>
    (this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, string> converter, string separator)
{
    return string.Join(separator, source.Select(converter).ToArray());
}

public static IEnumerable<T> FromDelimitedString<T>
    (this string source, Func<string, T> converter, params string[] separator)
{
    return source.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.None).Select(converter);
}
```

And here are a few examples of usage:

```
int[] source1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

string txt1 = source1.ToDelimitedString(x => x.ToString(), "|");
Console.WriteLine(txt1);    // "1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|10"

int[] dest1 = txt1.FromDelimitedString(x => int.Parse(x), "|").ToArray();
Console.WriteLine(source1.SequenceEqual(dest1));    // "True"

// ...

string[] source2 = new[] { "Fish & Chips", "Salt & Pepper", "Gin & Tonic" };

string txt2 = source2.ToDelimitedString(x => HttpUtility.UrlEncode(x), "&");
Console.WriteLine(txt2);    // "Fish+%26+Chips&Salt+%26+Pepper&Gin+%26+Tonic"

var dest2 = txt2.FromDelimitedString(x => HttpUtility.UrlDecode(x), "&");
Console.WriteLine(source2.SequenceEqual(dest2));    // "True"
```

Answer (score 2):

You must use split and join:

Here is a good article about it:

http://www.csharp-station.com/HowTo/StringJoinSplit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know which primitive types you will be using, you can loop through to form a single string using a space (or whatever you choose) as a delimiter, then use the String.Split() method to split the string back out into a string array, and finally loop through that array and cast its members to reproduce the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Split/Join is good but what if in your string will 
be separator sign?
I suggest to use some encoding, Base64 for example.